# Making caller information attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

As far as I know there are some caller information attribute since C# 5.0 like `[CallerMemberName]`, `[CallerFilePath]`.

Is there a good way to make new attribute like that?

I want to change

```
public void Regist<T>(object recipient, Action<T> action)
```

to like this.

```
public void Regist<T>([CallerObject]object recipient, Action<T> action)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. Firstly, no you cant, well unless you want to edit the compiler (however we would need to see the problem you are actually trying to solve). Secondly you should be asking the question about your specific problem and letting people who know the language and its features well suggest solutions

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I edited my question more detail. But you sounded like there is no way.

Comment: So you just want the calling class ?

Comment: Yes. I keep putting recipient to 'this'. I think it's really bad. I hope there is a good way to make it simple.

Comment: Have you thought about an extension method and if it might help ? `Regist<T>(this object recipient,...`

Comment: I really appreciate to your comments. it sound really great. but I think It doesn't go well with my design. the function I wrote is in the singleton class. And there are some functions like 'Send' as well. I wanted to them in the same class. That's why I made a class. Thank you.

Comment: Very unclear what you want to achieve. @MichaelRandall seem to got some idea what you want, but I don't see what it is... Obviously you can create attribute `class CallerObjectAttribute:Attribute` that let you compile sample shown in the post... but what  you expect this syntax to do is unclear.